# scala-plicking utilizado em classes comuns

Tags: scala

Estou tentando usar o scala-pickling pois o site no [github](https://github.com/scala/pickling) faz parecer que se trata de uma ferramenta muito simples de se usar. O fato é que não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar o simples trecho a seguir (em REPL):

```
scala> import scala.pickling._
import scala.pickling._

scala> import scala.pickling.Defaults._
import scala.pickling.Defaults._

scala> import binary._
import binary._

scala> class Xpto { var a = 0D; var b = 0 }
defined class Xpto

scala> val v = new Xpto { a = 1.23; b = 5 }
v: Xpto = $anon$1@636d2b03

scala> v.pickle
<console>:19: error: type mismatch;
 found   : v.type (with underlying type Xpto)
 required: ?{def pickle: ?}
Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:
 both method PickleOps in package pickling of type [T](picklee: T)pickling.PickleOps[T]
 and method pickleOps in trait Ops of type [T](picklee: T)scala.pickling.PickleOps[T]
 are possible conversion functions from v.type to ?{def pickle: ?}
          v.pickle
            ^
<console>:19: error: value pickle is not a member of Xpto
                  v.pickle
                    ^
```

O quê posso estar fazendo de errado?

Obs.: Estou usando a seguinte referência em **build.sbt**:

```
"org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-pickling" % "0.10.1"
```

Comment: Eu consegui compilar esse código, com essa mesma versão do pickling. A única diferença é que usei uma worksheet em vez da REPL....

Answer (score 0):

há muitas funções implícitas com a mesma assinatura sendo trazidas

```scala
// importa a case class PickleOps que define a função pickle
import scala.pickling._
// importa as funções do objeto Defaults
// que por herança traz tb o método pickleOps
import scala.pickling.Defaults._
```

experimente diminuir os `imports` e usar apenas o que precisa

ainda prefiro usar uma `case class` ao invés de uma classe "normal", essa é uma boa prática pra entidades do tipo modelo, vc vai notar que o resultado da serialização será mais "limpa", por causa de facilidades que uma `case class` traz

outra dica, para serializar json recomendo a [json lib do playframework](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaJson) que tb é muito simples e eficiente